# "status": 500, "message": "Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, twilio, try-catch

**This question is resolved by Adding *await* before client.messages.create**
I am trying to send a WhatsApp message using Twilio. the following is the Code

```
const accountSid = '************************';
const authToken = '*************************';

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    const client = require('rds/node_modules/twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
    try {
        console.log("Inside Try");
        client.messages
            .create({ 
                body: 'You are free to change it and write whatever you like.',
                from: 'whatsapp:**********',
                to: 'whatsapp:*********'
            }).then(message => {
                console.log("outbound SMS sent Successfuly :");
                console.log(message.sid);

                callback(null, {
                    statusCode: 200,
                    message: "Outbount message Sent Succesfuly :" + message.sid
                });
            }).done().catch(error => {
                console.log("Error occurred while sending outbound SMS," + error);
                 callback(null, {
                     status: 500,
                    message: "Error occurred while sending outbound SMS," + error
                });
            });
    
        
    }
    catch(error){
        //console.log("Error occurred while sending outbound SMS," + error);
        callback(null, {
            status: 500,
            message: "Error " + error
        });
    }
};
```

WhatsApp messages get sent successfully but I get this response as well

```
"status": 500,   "message": "Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined"
```

and if I remove either done() or catch(error). I don't  get any error message and it doesn't send wahtsapp message

Answer (score 1):

You already mentioned the question that the `done()` invocation is the cause of this error. Your logic should be good if you remove it.

The other mentioned problem (that you don't receive the message) is probably due to the message payload that does **neither match a [message template](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates#creating-message-templates-and-submitting-them-for-approval) nor belongs to an [ongoing 24-hour session](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates#sending-non-template-messages-within-a-24-hour-session)**.

You should be able to find the detailed error message in the messaging logs in the Console. Note that errors from Meta/Whatsapp's servers will only appear there and they **won't trigger a runtime error**:
[image]

Comment: I know what the cause of the error response but 
If I remove the **done()** or **Catch()** the Code between client.message and catch doesn't even execute. so I am not getting any error log in the Twilio console.

Comment: I have another problem with the incoming WhatsApp messages. I get the encoded messages. after decoding the message it's still not in good form,
Thanks

Comment: I solved it,  I just added the **await** before client.message.create
thanks for Your response. <3
You can close the Question.

Comment: that would be Good If you share Code for Incoming WhatsApp messages.

Comment: @Amjad you can either close the question yourself, or mark this answer as correct if it helped. As for receiving WhatsApp messages, check out [this tutorial for receiving messages and responding in Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-and-receive-media-messages-whatsapp-nodejs#respond-with-media-in-whatsapp).

Comment: Thanks, @philnash. I will close this Question.

Comment: I'm glad you where able to solve the problem. 

PS: As comments might be ignored or disappear in the future, it would be great if you could add the **await** hint in your original question.

Comment: @IObert and philnash, The message sending APIs for WhatsApp and general SMS, both missing await in its Node js Code provided by Twilio.
that would be good if Twilio add it to its APIs as my Message didn't get sent in both WhatsApp and general SMS intill I add **await**

Comment: That's interesting. To which code provided by Twilio are you referring to? I'm happy to check :)